# Is there any way to autofill OTP Text Field from incoming SMS in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have this following text field for OTP Code. As far as I know I need to specify `autoFillHints` to `AutofillHints.oneTimeCode` for flutter to autocomplete text field from incoming SMS. You can see my text field below. Is there any way to autocomplete otp field from SMS in Flutter (Without using any package)?. Thanks in advance.

```
 Form(
                      key: controller.fOtpCode,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        key: const Key(LoginScreen.otpTextFieldKey),
                        validator: (_) => controller.cOtpCode.text.isOTPCode(),
                        onFieldSubmitted: (_) => controller.onTapSendOtpCode(),
                        autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.oneTimeCode],
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        controller: controller.cOtpCode,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/otp_autofill)

```
  late OTPTextEditController controller;
  late OTPInteractor _otpInteractor;
  TextEditingController otpCon = TextEditingController();

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _otpInteractor = OTPInteractor();
    _otpInteractor
        .getAppSignature()
    //ignore: avoid_print
        .then((value) => print('signature - $value'));

    controller = OTPTextEditController(
      codeLength: 5,
      //ignore: avoid_print
      onCodeReceive: (code) => print('Your Application receive code - $code'),
      otpInteractor: _otpInteractor,
    )..startListenUserConsent(
          (code) {
            RegExp regex = RegExp(r'\d+');
            RegExpMatch? match = regex.firstMatch(code ?? "");
            String otpString = match?.group(0) ?? "";
            otpCon.text = otpString;
        return otpString;
      },
      strategies: [
        SampleStrategy(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

This is the `SampleStrategy` class where you can set the duration of listening incoming sms.

```
class SampleStrategy extends OTPStrategy {
  @override
  Future<String> listenForCode() {
    return Future.delayed(
      const Duration(minutes: 5),
          () => 'Your code is 54321',
    );
  }
}
```